# Meaning of `$` when used as argument to map

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I understand that the $ operator is for avoiding parentheses. Anything appearing after it will take precedence over anything that comes before.

I am trying to understand what it means in this context:

```
map ($ 3) [(+),(-),(/),(*)]
```

With the following code:

```
instance Show (a -> b) where
  show a = function

main = putStrLn $ show $ map ($ 3) [(+),(-),(/),(*)]
```

The output is

```
["function", "function", "function", "function"]
```

This doesn't help me understand the meaning of the $ here.
How can I display more helpful output?

Comment: This code won't even compile, I assume that by `function` you mean `"function"`. And, while it's valid code, please leave spaces between operators and their operands, `putStrLn$show$map` is much harder to mentally parse than `putStrLn $ show $ map`

Comment: to display more helpful output, enter: `map ($ 4) $ map ($ 3) [(+),(-),(/),(*)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) is a function that takes a function as first parameter, and a value as second and returns the value applied to that function.

For example:

```
Prelude> (1+) $ 2
3
```

The expression `($ 3)` is an example of [*infix operator sectioning* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator). `($ 3)` is short for `\f -> f $ 3`, or simpler `\f -> f 3`. It thus is a function that takes a function and applies `3` to that function.

For your expression:

```
map ($ 3) [(+),(-),(/),(*)]
```

the output is thus equivalent to:

```
[(3+), (3-), (3/), (3*)] :: Fractional a => [a -> a]
```

Since `(+), (-), (*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` work with types that are members of the `Num` typeclass, and `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` works with types that are members of the `Fractional` type class, and all `Fractional` types are num types as well, `3` is here a `Fractional` type, and the list thus contains functions that are all of the type `a -> a` with `a` a member of `Fractional`.

> How can I display more helpful output?

The compiler does not keep track of the expressions, as specified in the Haskell wiki page on [*`Show` instance for functions* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions).

> The Haskell compiler doesn't maintain the expressions as they are, but translates them to machine code or some other low-level representation. The function `\x -> x - x + x :: Int -> Int` might have been optimized to `\x -> x :: Int -> Int`. If it's used anywhere, it might have been inlined and optimized to nothing. The variable name x is not stored anywhere. (...)

So we can not "look inside" the function and derive an expression that is human-readable.